# Thermal cameras - what is the practical significance of NEDT in relation to accuracy?

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors, optics, thermal-radiation

(Hi, I put this question on the elec eng. stack exchange and someone suggested I move it here. This question has also been edited to make the actual question clearer and fix an error).

Using accuracy and NEDT specifications, is there a way to estimate the approximate error in a temperature gradient when taken across different parts of an animal within a single photograph? e.g. If the photo shows the max foot temperature is 31.0°C and the max eye temp is 32.5°C. Is there a way to estimate the approximate uncertainty in the 1.5°C difference between the max eye and foot temperatures within the same image?  Or perhaps someone might be able to explain why it is not possible to do this and/or explain why I am wrong (below) and the accuracy specification on any gradient **is** 4°C.
(Please assume just for the purpose of this question, that the foot and eye have identical very high emissivity (~0.98) and that the resolution of the camera i.e. no. of pixels is high enough so that it is not affecting anything).

Further clarification as to why I think the error may be better than 2 x accuracy specification (4°C)

I am using a thermal camera (Therm-app TH) to take photographs of small mammals. The accuracy rating is ±2°C. The specifications of this camera are quite similar to those of many cameras used in zoological studies recently. I have tested the camera against distilled water, which has similar emissivity to many small mammals and the temperatures given in the photograph are within ±2°C of the true temperature. (From my tests the error certainly can get up to ±2°C and was not predictable).

The camera is rated to have NEDT (noise equivalent differential temperature) <0.07 °C.
Most of my photographs have around 5 °C to 12 °C difference across the entire animal (e.g. animal surface temps might vary between 14°C and 21°C if Ta is 10°C). I can very clearly see the animal in the thermal photographs and the different parts such as nose, ears, body and claws are sharp and clear. However if the accuracy is ±2°C, and the accuracy of every pixel is completely independent of all other pixels then any two randomly chosen pixels of the same true temperature could theoretically be up to 4°C apart in the image. I don't think this makes sense, as if this was the case there is no reason for certain body parts to be the same temperature, for example the entire ventral area only varies by 1 °C rather than 4°C that might be expected if error in each pixel was independent of the surrounding pixels. Therefore, unless I am missing something else, I assume there must be some sort of calibration so that the direction of the error is fairly consistent across all pixels and the error in the **difference** between temperatures taken on different parts of the animal within the same image would be less than ±2°C.  Perhaps this is related to the NEDT specification?

Comment: Which question are you asking? Practical significance or maximum error or uncertainty?

Comment: @SolarMike   this one would be most helpful....using accuracy and NEDT specifications, is there a way to calculate the maximum error of a temperature gradient when taken across a single photograph? e.g. If the photo shows the max foot temperature is 31.0°C and the max eye temp is 32.5°C is there a way to calculate the uncertainty in the 1.5°C difference between the max eye and foot temperatures? Or perhaps someone might be able to explain why it is not possible to do this...... thanks!

Comment: Your last paragraph contains two questions that are, if not contradictory, then separate.  Is there a way to know using _just_ accuracy and NETD specifications -- no.  Is there a way to calculate the uncertainty in that 1.5 C difference -- yes.  But _how_ you do that calculation is involved enough that I think it warrants a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

NETD means that if you have neighboring patches that differ by the NEDT, then the difference in response at the detector will be just equal to the thermal noise.  This is probably going to be below the threshold that you could perceive yourself, unless the patches were of known size and you had practice seeing the difference.

But that says nothing about the accuracy of the temperature measurement of the two patches.

For instance say you have a patch at 39 degrees C and a patch at 37 degrees C.  By the NEDT, these should be fairly easily distinguishable.  But that NEDT doesn't mean they won't read as 37 and 35, or 41 and 39.

> For example, using accuracy and NEDT specifications, is there a way to calculate the maximum error of a temperature gradient when taken across a single photograph?

Not from just that information, no.  The emissivity of the fur matters, as does the fact that you'll be 'seeing' photons emitted from fur at various depths, depending on how dense the fur actually is.  I would expect, in fact, that unless your research subjects happen to have an emissivity of almost 1, that even if you had a perfect *camera*, the errors involved in inferring an animal's temperature from it's emitted thermal radiation will be larger than 2 degrees C.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,  I understand most of that so I think possible I need to rephrase my question, not sure if that's allowed once people have already started answering.  Mostly I it's really the last part of your answer that I am interested in...... if I know the emissivity is 0.99 and it is the same on all parts of the animal, it can be shaved and painted black if that's better,  can I calculate the error in the difference between different parts, for example maybe it is a bat and the camera says the center of the wing is 31.0 C and the outer edge is 32.5 C

Comment: so the difference is 1.5C,  I feel like even though both those values could be out by up to 2C,  the error in the difference must be much less than 2C.  Or is this incorrect? And if it is incorrrect why? Or if this is correct and the error is much less than 2C could I calculate the approximate error in that 1.5C gradient, and then say the true error in the gradient is likely to be closer to 'x' but will be slightly worse than 'x' that due to parameters such as emissivity which will be slightly different on different parts of the animal however it is likely to be much better than 2C.

Comment: Yes you can edit your question, and are encouraged to do so in cases like this.  The comment about shaving and painting black was facetious -- that's how you would hit high emissivity if you're not sure of it.  According to [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324261578_Measuring_the_emissivity_of_mammal_pelage) you can't count on the emissivity being close to one -- I don't know animals, but I know that in thermography people often discount emissivity because it's counter-intuitive if you happen to be an animal that sees using reflected light.

Comment: thanks, I will edit once I get  a bit more spare time, and put a more emphasis on the last part.  re. "that NEDT doesn't mean they won't read as 37 and 35, or 41 and 39"  . If this is correct I think it means that the absolute error of a gradient could be up to 4 deg. From what I've seen, unless I'm misunderstanding something else, it also probably means there are many incorrect scientific studies of gradients of animal temperature using thermal cameras out there. I hope this is not the case.

Comment: As mentioned above, I think this last bit should be a separate question, more on the lines of "how to measure" than "can you measure".  The answer is that it's probably a lot more than NETD but may be significantly less than the worst-case endpoints assuming full error on each one.  It'll depend on details of emissivity, the ambient temperature, what temperature (i.e. flesh or fur) that you actually want to measure, and details of the emissivity vs. depth characteristics of the fur in question.